Annotate the property of return value is not null
With C#11 we can tell the compiler that a return value of a method is not null like this:
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(input))]
public static string? SomeMethod(string? input)
{
    ...
}

Now I have a class as return value:
class Bar
{
    public string? Foo{ get; set; }
}

And following method:
public static Bar CreateCompleteBar(string? input)
{
    return new Bar { Foo = input };
}

How can I tell the compiler that CreateCompleteBar("x").Foo is not null?

You have a typo in your Bar method; it should say return new Bar { Foo = input };
